# PyEnv alternative to manage multiple versions of Python on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, python3

I have a system developed in Python and I need to run the tests on all versions 3.5 and above. On Unix it is possible to use the PyEnv dependency manager and install all versions but it does not work on windows outside of 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' and I can only use windows 7.

What is the best recommendation for running multiple versions of python simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [PyEnv fork for Windows](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) that may do what you need, though it's missing some commands. Probably your best bet if you want to keep the PyEnv commands you're familiar with.

If you don't mind switching to a tool that works on all OSes, give [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) a try. It'll let you create different environments for different projects with different python versions just like PyEnv.